# Time values not correctly checked for equivalence in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have Excel 2007. I have two time values, say A1=6:20 and B1=6:10, and I'm finding their difference and checking if its equivalent to another value, let's say C1=0:10. So when I put in cell D1=(A1-B1)=C1, I expect TRUE, but I get FALSE.

I assume this is related to how time​ values are stored. When I get rid of custom formatting from hh:mm to General, it says A1-B1=0.006944444, which is the same value stored for 0:10. This could be related to floating point precision. I tried doing set precision as displayed, but that didn't do anything. If I do 0:10 in one cell and 0:10 in another it says they are equivalent, but for some reason it's telling me the difference of 6:20 and 6:10 isn't equivalent to 0:10, even though that it was is displayed and stored.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I think you can't calculate time format :) It only can plus/minus ... etc when reformatting to general or number.

Comment: If you keep expanding the decimal you will see why `00:10` = `0.006944444444444440` and `6:20-6:10` = `0.006944444444444420`

Comment: You can compare minutes like this: `=MINUTE(A1-B1)=MINUTE(C1)`

Comment: This also works: `=TIME(HOUR(A1-B1),MINUTE(A1-B1),SECOND(A1-B1))=C1`

Comment: @scott-craner why are they different in decimal form?

Comment: One turns it into time, basically rounds the number, and the other without, is just subtracting numbers without the rounding.